# Where is the configuration file for my custom plugins?

Tags: 8

In my development environment, I create my first plugins that uses REST with a GET method. I use Rest UI to declare my plugins directly inside Drupal.

All is ok, the request sends me the json result as expected.

But, from here, my questions are :

- Rest UI avoid to declare manually a config file. Great. But after using Rest UI I'm not able to find the config file, where is the configuration saved ?
- In production, must I install Rest UI too, and re-configure my plugin ? Or is it possible to just copy/paste a configuration file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For configuration to be found as a file (yml) you have to manually invoke/export it with any of the following methods

1. from the Drupal admin interface visiting the url `admin/config/development/configuration/single/export`. For this to work the core `Configuration Manager` module must be enabled.
2. drush with [drush config-export](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/config/config-export/) and than finding the appropriate file manually
3. drupal console [drupal config:export:single](https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/commands/config-export-single.html)
4. contrib modules such as [config_single_export](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_single_export) or [config_partial_export](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_partial_export)

All those methods above have also an import mechanism which you can use to import or see [more details here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221592/import-a-single-yml-configuration-file)

Also note you will not need the REST UI module to be enabled in production

Comment: Thx, it's ok for me !