# How can I export only one paragraph type, the fields, the form settings and the display settings?

Tags: drush, configuration, paragraphs

Some days ago I've exported and imported a full configuration with `drush cex` and `drush cim`.

What are the steps to **export 1 paragraph type including the fields, form settings, display settings** etc ...

I'm using a multisite, so it would be great to copy them from one site to the other sites within the multisite.

**Can I:**

1. `drush cex` site 1
2. **copy exported .yml files** to other site in folder (sites/site1.multisite.com/files/config_HASH/sync)
3. **Delete all .yml files except those needed** for the import of my paragraph type?

I guess there are **better methods** to establish this?

Comment: Don't do that, drush cim deletes configs not present in the sync folder. Use a different folder and the `--partial` option. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221592/import-a-single-yml-configuration-file

Comment: To copy config from one site to another you may have a look at the [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features) module. Export feature on one site, import it in another, export config on both sites, done. One feature always only contains the partial config you decide.

Comment: @4K4 good to know about the deletion.
It looks like it is not that simple. I need to test this on a development site.

Comment: With Features you also can easily keep track of changes and then sync them on the other site(s) again.

Comment: "I guess there are better methods to establish this?" is purely opinion based and depends on the use case. For the narrower question about drush cim I think the linked question is a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import a single yml configuration file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221592/import-a-single-yml-configuration-file)

Comment: @4k4: the approach to create a module to bundle a list of predefined paragraph types looks interesting, because this is something you can re-use in other projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module is for. Syncing partial config across multi-site instances.

> The features module enables the capture and management of features in
> Drupal. A feature is a collection of Drupal entities which taken
> together satisfy a certain use-case.
>
> Features provides a UI and API for taking different site building
> components from modules with exportables and bundling them together in
> a single feature module. A feature module is like any other Drupal
> module except that it contains additional information in its info file
> so that configuration can be checked, updated, or reverted
> programmatically.

That means you would create a feature on your main multi-site instance which contains the paragraph type. Have it placed inside the modules/features/ folder. Related config will be added automatically. You then enable the feature (which basically is just another module) in another multi-site instance. The config will be imported into the database. On both multi-site instances you then export config as usual. Because every multi-site instance still is managed from its own config. Which then also contains the synced paragraphs config.

As soon as you add another field to the paragraph type on either multi-site instance Features will recognise the changes. You then can recreate your paragraph feature and import the changes on another multi-site instance (into the database). Finally, on both sites again export config as usual (which then also contains the paragraph types you've synced via Features). Features enables you to keep track of changes to a feature via built-in diffing, which after you recreated the feature (partial config gets exported) can be synced into the database on other multi-site instances again.

Of course Features also comes with a set of Drush commands to make your live easier.

Comment: "then export config as usual" please explain in more detail. Keep in mind that config in this case) is not equal on all the different sites within the multisite approach.

Comment: @Lance – Yep, that's exactly why you manage each site from their own config (as usual). The Features module only is a helper to sync partial config **into the database**. From where it must be exported as site-dependant (normal) config. On live/prod then you leave the features untouched, you just import config (which then also contains the paragraph type on both sites).

Comment: So if I create a paragraph type on the main site (or other) then with Features you can manage to only export that specific paragraph type with all settings and import it into the other site? Without using drush cmd? I did not yet install the module, so it is a guess.

Comment: @Lance – Exactly. Because features are just modules in the end. Of course Features  also comes with a set of Drush commands to export and import changes. When exporting an updated feature the module will then be rewritten and you can then go to your other multi-site where Features will tell you, hey there are changes in the feature module which ain't active on that site here, do you want me to import them? They then can be imported into the active config of this instance's database. From where you export the instance-specific config as usual, because every instance still has its own config.

Comment: I have now both modules available on both sites (sounds logic in a multisite environment). I have only enabled the module on the site where I did not have the new content type. On the source sites I do not have to activate it right?

Comment: Activate it on both sites. So that also on the source site Features is able to track changes to the paragraph type (new field, new display settings, whatever).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115119/discussion-between-lance-and-leymannx).

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is make custom modules and add the specific yml files to config/install. This way you can just enable the module on other websites.

A good way of working could be a custom module named custom_paragraphs with a .info file and a modules folder. Within this module all your submodules per paragraph type.

- custom_paragraphs

  - custom_paragraphs.info.yml
  - modules

    - custom_paragraphs_two_column

      - custom_paragraphs_two_column.info (add dependencies here!)
      - config

        - install

          - (all the yaml files here)
    - custom_paragraphs_slider

      - ...

Update a module by using:

```
drush config-import --partial --source=modules/custom/custom_paragraphs/modules/custom_paragraphs_two_column/config/install
```

Comment: That's exactly what Features does for you.

Comment: @leymannx, yeah but why need contrib for this?

Comment: Because it takes care of all the manual work you need to do otherwise. It also enables you to easily keep track of changes via built-in diffing and sync capabilities when something changes. No need to reinvent the wheel in a way.

Comment: I see. Both are an option. Features also adds some complexity.

Comment: Indeed both are an option, but I prefer the custom module a little more ... maybe I need to test both to make a conclusion.

Comment: @StefVanLooveren while this answer is a good start, can we extend this question with a simple example. For instance, one paragraph with the two column example? And also what todo when you update the module and want to copy them to the same module used on an other website for instance?

Comment: @Lance create the paragraph "Two column" and export to your general configuration. Then, paste all the files containing filename two_column in the config/install folder of the custom submodule. Then enable the module on website 2.